# jquery mobile button doesn't have the color change effect when it cause the click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I have a problem in use the jquery mobile button;
If I use the button like this:

```
<a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-theme="b">SKIP</a>
```

It would have the color change effect while click it;
But now I want to pass something to next page,so I have to use another way like

```
    <head >
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <title>jQuery Mobile Demos</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js">   </script>
       <script type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>    
   <body>
     <div id="test.html" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="btn">SKIP</a>
        </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('click','#btn',function(event){
        $.mobile.changePage("index.html");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Then the problem was happen,and the button no longer have the color change effect..
Is anybody can do me a favor?

Comment: if you add fiddle, that will help more to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe use it by adding a `href="#"` and then using `e.preventDefault()` in the `click` binding :

**Markup**

```
<a data-role="button" href="#" data-theme="b" id="btn">SKIP</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click','#btn',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.mobile.changePage("index.html");
});
```